# \crefstripprefix not working for 10 or more cross-refs

Tags: cleveref

The following MWE gives an error; if the number of cross-referenced equations is reduced to below 10, the error disappears. The `\crefrangeformat` is totally standard and is taken from many answers on this site. If `\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}` is replaced with `#2`, the error also disappears.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,cleveref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\crefrangeformat{equation}{(#3#1#4--#5\crefstripprefix{#1}{#2}#6)}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{3} % just for this example

\begin{gather}
\label{1}   1\\
\label{2}   2\\
\label{3}   3\\
\label{4}   4\\
\label{5}   5\\
\label{6}   6\\
\label{7}   7\\
\label{8}   8\\
\label{9}   9\\
\label{10} 10 
\end{gather}

\cref{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What you're getting is not an *error*, but an admittedly very cryptic warning message. For now, just type "r" (for "run") and continue the compilation -- the output of both `\cref{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and `\crefrange{1}{10}` will be correct. Really! A separate thought: You may want to contact the author and maintainer of the `cleveref` package -- his name and email address are stated on the front page of the user guide of the `cleveref` package -- and provide a link to this posting. Then ask him if the issue you've come across is a bug and, if so, if he might be willing to provide a fix.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well; has it been reported to the cleveref maintainers? If so, was there a response?